# ¿Por qué me da el error de violación de segmento?

Tags: c++, punteros

mi duda que tengo es que estoy mirando por internet y he probado cosas y no se como crear un objeto dinámico y dentro del objeto dinámico inicializar arrays dinámicos y varios atributos. He probado varias formas y me salen errores, ahora mismo me da que tengo violacion del segmento.

El valor de nPrendas es un valor global, no deberia de haber problema con ello. Seguramente el error sea que no he entendido algun concepto, pero no se como avanzar, gracias.

La función principal es backtracking que es llamado por el main.

```
struct Solucion{
    int *sActual;
    int *sMejor;
    int dActual;
    int dMejor;
};
```

```
void iniciar(Solucion* S){
    S->sActual = new int[nPrendas];
    memset(S->sActual,-1,sizeof(int)*nPrendas);
    S->sMejor = new int[nPrendas];
    memset(S->sMejor,-1,sizeof(int)*nPrendas);
    S->dActual = 0;
    S->dMejor = 0;

}
```

```
void borrar(Solucion* S){
    delete[] S->sActual;
    delete[] S->sMejor;
}
```

```
void backtracking()
{   
    Solucion *S;
    iniciar(S);
    borrar(S);
    delete S;

}
```

Comment: Normal que te de excepción. Creas un puntero a `Solución` y no le asignas memoria (`new`), y llamas a `iniciar` que lo primero que hace es `S->sActual`. Pero `S` apunta a una dirección de memoria que no has reservado. Y ahí tienes la primera excepción. Te dar´amás cuando intentes borrarlo con `delete`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todo el problema radica en este bloque de código:

```cpp
void backtracking()
{   
    Solucion *S; //<-- aquí
    iniciar(S);
    borrar(S);
    delete S;

}
```

Si te das cuenta, el puntero `S` en ningún momento le asignas una dirección base de un objeto, queda con contenido basura y esta es la razón del porque da una falla de segmentación (acceder a memoria que no le pertenece al programa).

**Solución:** Debes reservar memoria con `new`.

```cpp
void backtracking()
{   
    Solucion *S = new Solucion; 
    iniciar(S);
    borrar(S);
    delete S;
}
```

De este modo, el puntero `S` apuntará a un objeto que si le pertenece al programa.

A pesar que con esto debería de solucionarse todo, hay otro problema y es que tampoco le asignaste ninguna dirección al miembro `sMejor` y esto ocasiona que ocurra un fallo de segmentación.

Así debería de quedar:

```cpp
void iniciar(Solucion* S){
    S->sActual = new int[nPrendas];
    memset(S->sActual,-1,sizeof(int)*nPrendas);
    cout<<"ERROR INICIAR1"<<endl;
    //Se reserva un array de X elementos y se asigna la dirección base del array a sMejor.
    S->sMejor = new int[nPrendas];
    memset(S->sMejor,-1,sizeof(int)*nPrendas);
    S->dActual = 0;
    S->dMejor = 0;
}
```

**Actualización:**

Si el parámetro de la función `iniciar` lo cambias a `Solucion&`, entonces `S` será una referencia a `Solucion`, así que solo podrás pasar un argumento de tipo `Solucion` y no de tipo `Solucion*`.

**Ejemplo del error:**

```cpp
void iniciar(Solucion& S)
{
   //code
}

void backtracking()
{   
    Solucion* S = new Solucion; 
    iniciar(S); //error de compilación.
}
```

Una posible solución es declarar el parámetro `S` como una referencia a un puntero a `Solucion`, de este modo, podrás modificar el contenido del puntero y el objeto al que apunte.

**Ejemplo:**

```cpp
void iniciar(Solucion*& S)
{
    S->sActual = new int[nPrendas];
    memset(S->sActual,-1,sizeof(int)*nPrendas);
    cout<<"ERROR INICIAR1"<<endl;
    S->sMejor = new int[nPrendas];
    memset(S->sMejor,-1,sizeof(int)*nPrendas);
    S->dActual = 0;
    S->dMejor = 0;
}
```

Una segunda solución sería usar un almacenamiento automático (es decir, el objeto se crea cuando la función inicia y se destruye cuando la rutina termine su ejecución):

```cpp
void iniciar(Solucion& S)
{
   //code
}

void backtracking()
{   
    //El objeto tiene un almacenamiento automático.
    Solucion S; 
    iniciar(S); 
}
```

Y de este modo, evitas reservar memoria y liberarlo. No olvides que en la función `iniciar` debes usar el operador `.` para poder acceder a los miembros de la estructura.

Código completo (**solución 2**):

```cpp
void borrar(Solucion& S){
    delete[] S.sActual;
    delete[] S.sMejor;
}

void iniciar(Solucion& S)
{
    S.sActual = new int[nPrendas];
    memset(S.sActual,-1,sizeof(int)*nPrendas);
    cout<<"ERROR INICIAR1"<<endl;
    S.sMejor = new int[nPrendas];
    memset(S.sMejor,-1,sizeof(int)*nPrendas);
    S.dActual = 0;
    S.dMejor = 0;
}

void backtracking()
{   
    Solucion S;
    iniciar(S);
    borrar(S);
}
```

Y listo, la solución dos es más sencilla que la primera.

Comment: Vale si, tienes razon en todo, borre sin querer cuando le asignaba a sMejor, queria borrar el comentario de arriba. MI pregunta ahora, para pasar S y modificarlo en iniciar, En iniciar no deberia ser iniciar(Solucion &S) en vez de iniciar(Solucion* S), con el aspersand me da error

Comment: @oskarlopez4 He actualiza la respuesta. Espero te sirva!